# Tab Bar with Large Icons

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish a tab bar with only large icons, I have attached an image below for reference.  I am not interested in creating my own tab bar controller, and managing the view controllers myself.

[image]

Comment: I searched a lot, nothing came up. I ended up subclassing `UITabBarController`,what is the reason not to use subclass?

Comment: I thought this was considered a class you should not subclass, but if you did and had luck, would you mind showing kind of what you did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution, i created a class which is a subclass of `UITabBarController`.

**CustomTabBarController.h**

```
@interface CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
@end
```

**CustomTabBarController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect tabBarFrame = self.tabBar.frame ;
    tabBarFrame.origin.y -= kOrigin;
    tabBarFrame.size.height = kTabBarHeight;
    self.tabBar.frame = tabBarFrame;
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    /* Tab Bar Background */

    UIImage *tabBarBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarBackgroundImage.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackgroundImage];

    /* Tab Bar Item */
    UIButton *surveyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [surveyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(surveyButtonDidSelect) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    surveyButton.tag = surveyButtonTag;
    [surveyButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGRect surveyButtonFrame = surveyButton.frame ;
    surveyButtonFrame.origin.x = /*Proper value in your case */;
    surveyButtonFrame.origin.y = /*Proper value in your case */;
    surveyButtonFrame.size.height = /*Proper value in your case */ ;
    surveyButtonFrame.size.width =/*Proper value in your case */;
    surveyButton.frame = surveyButtonFrame;
    [self.tabBar addSubview:surveyButton];

    UIButton *statusButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    statusButton.tag = statusButtonTag;
    [statusButton addTarget:self action:@selector(statusButtonDidSelect) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [statusButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGRect statusButtonFrame = statusButton.frame ;
    statusButtonFrame.origin.x = /*Proper value in your case */;
    statusButtonFrame.origin.y = /*Proper value in your case */;
    statusButtonFrame.size.height = /*Proper value in your case */;
    statusButtonFrame.size.width = /*Proper value in your case */;
    statusButton.frame = statusButtonFrame;
    [self.tabBar addSubview:statusButton];
}

-(void)surveyButtonDidSelect
{
    self.selectedIndex = 0 ;
}
-(void)statusButtonDidSelect
{
    self.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

It's working for me,and i got no problem.
Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @limon's answer, if you want to change the height of the custom UITabBar, I found from another SO answer, sorry do not remember web link reference, the following code did the trick and locked it at the bottom as well, where I found with @limon's code the UITabBar was not position flush at bottom out of the box with his code:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    //UITabBar Height
    var tabFrame: CGRect = self.tabBar.frame
    tabFrame.size.height = 75
    tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 75
    self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
}
```

Obviously you want to remove the similar code from limon's answer or maybe move his entire code snippet to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` I didn't try that, I called his code in my `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

The max size for the image in a tab bar on an iPhone 5/iPhone 4 is 96 x 64 so you are somewhat limited there without rolling your own.  Though in your example image those may fit in the constraints.